# Replacement of 'Str2UnixSockAddr' which is marked as deprecated

Tags: sockets, freepascal, fpc

I'm using the function 'Str2UnixSockAddr' from the sockets unit in Freepascal for programming unix-domain-sockets. But I ever get the warning that is marked as deprecated. 
What is the replacement for that function that is not deprecated?

Comment: I think it was deprecated only because it was shortstring, and a replacement was not yet added. IOW when it is fixed only the warning will go away, and it will take the ansistring variant.

Comment: It's fine working for me but i'm a little surprised about the Deprecated state on that function.

Comment: I think there also was a discussion about moving unix socket helpers to unit unix (since sockets is theoretically wholly portable).

Comment: move it without deprecated to the unix, osx unit would make it clearer, that would be fine